# How to refresh a StatusBar based on several ViewModels?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, viewmodel, mvvm-light, statusbar, win-universal-app

I develop an **Universal App**, that uses **MVVM Light** and **Navegar**. In this app, the main page contains a **Pivot**, where each **PivotItem** is bounded to a **ViewModel**.

This page looks like this:

[image]

The XAML looks like this:

```
    <Page
        ...>
        <Page.DataContext>
            <Binding Path="MainViewModelInstance" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
        </Page.DataContext>
        <Page.Resources>
            ...
        </Page.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <!-- HOME -->
            <Pivot x:Uid="homePivot" 
                   x:Name="homePivot" 
                   CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True" 
                   TitleTemplate="{StaticResource AppPivotTitle}"
                   Style="{StaticResource CustomizedPivot}">
                <Pivot.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"/>
                </Pivot.Background>
                <PivotItem x:Uid="homePivotitemHome"
                           Margin="19,14.5,19,0"
                           CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True" 
                           Header="Home">
                    <PivotItem.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Infos.background_image, Converter={StaticResource InfosUIImageFondToStringConverter}}" 
                                    Stretch="UniformToFill" 
                                    Opacity="0.75"/>
                    </PivotItem.Background>
                    </PivotItem.ContentTemplate>
                </PivotItem>

                <!-- NEWS -->
                <PivotItem x:Uid="homePivotitemNews"
                           Margin="19,14.5,0,0"
                           CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True" >
                    <PivotItem.DataContext>
                        <Binding Path="NewsViewModel" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
                    </PivotItem.DataContext>
                    <PivotItem.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding News}"
                                          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                          SelectionMode="Single"
                                          ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
                                    ...
                                </ListView>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </PivotItem.ContentTemplate>
                </PivotItem>

                <!-- CONTACTS -->
                <PivotItem x:Uid="homePivotitemContacts"
                           Margin="19,14.5,0,0"
                           CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True" 
                           Header="Contacts">
                    <PivotItem.DataContext>
                        <Binding Path="ContactsViewModel" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
                    </PivotItem.DataContext>
                    <PivotItem.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"
                                      IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                      SelectionMode="Single"
                                      ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
                                    ...

                                </ListView>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </PivotItem.ContentTemplate>
                </PivotItem>            
                ...
            </Pivot>
        </Grid>
    </Page>
```

So the page is bounded to a **DataContext** "***MainViewModelInstance***", that is used for the **first PivotItem**. The **others PivotItems** have their own **DataContext**: "***NewsViemodel***", "***ContactsViewModel***", ...

On each **ViewModel**, a constrctor calls a **L*oad()*** method that updates the datas of this HomePage.

I would like to display a **StatusBarProgressIndicator** when one of the ViewModels is loading datas, and stopping it when all datas has been loaded.

Currently I show the **StatusBarProgressIndicatorby** calling a "***ShowStatusBarProgress()***" method in the "***MainViewModel***":

```
    private async void LoadData()
    {
        ShowStatusbarProgress();
        // Load data
        ...
        HideStatusbarProgress();
    }

    private async void ShowStatusbarProgress()
    {
        progressbar.Text = "Please Wait...";
        await progressbar.ShowAsync();
    }

    private async void HideStatusbarProgress()
    {
        await progressbar.HideAsync();
    }
```

***But I don't see how to do for taking into account all the "Load()" methods of the ViewModels. I heard about Messenger services, but I don't see how it can work in my case.***

Comment: Messenger use could do the trick! A good tutorial can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx In short it is a decoupled way to send 'messages' of any kind between different objects. So you could create a LoadStarted and a LoadStopped message that is send from the different viewmodels and picked up by the MainViewModel